# Why displaying array elements capped at 100 in JavaScript and is there a way to display everything without a loop or splice()?

Tags: javascript, arrays, output

I have a function that returns every prime number from 2 to 1000 as an array.

```
/**
 * This function returns the array of all the prime numbers from 2 to 1000.
 * 
 * @returns {number[]} results
 */
function listPrimeNumbers() {
    var results = []; var j = 0;
    for(var num = 2; num <= 1000; num++) {
        var prime = true;
        for(var i = 2; i <= num / 2; i++) {
            if(num % i == 0) {
                prime = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(prime){
            results[j] = num;
            j++;
        } 
    }
    return results;
}
```

And I wanted to display all of it's contents to the screen:

```
console.log(listPrimeNumbers());
```

This is the output I'm getting:

```
[
    2,   3,   5,   7,  11,  13,  17,  19,  23,  29,  31,  37,
   41,  43,  47,  53,  59,  61,  67,  71,  73,  79,  83,  89,
   97, 101, 103, 107, 109, 113, 127, 131, 137, 139, 149, 151,
  157, 163, 167, 173, 179, 181, 191, 193, 197, 199, 211, 223,
  227, 229, 233, 239, 241, 251, 257, 263, 269, 271, 277, 281,
  283, 293, 307, 311, 313, 317, 331, 337, 347, 349, 353, 359,
  367, 373, 379, 383, 389, 397, 401, 409, 419, 421, 431, 433,
  439, 443, 449, 457, 461, 463, 467, 479, 487, 491, 499, 503,
  509, 521, 523, 541,
  ... 68 more items
]
```

It displays exactly 100 elements and then it says there are 68 more items in the array but it doesn't display the rest. Why is that happening? Why is it capped at 100? And is there a way that I can display the entire array without using a loop or `splice()` method?
`splice()` method kind of does the job but its output is not really what I was looking for...

```
console.log(listPrimeNumbers().slice(0,100)); 
console.log(listPrimeNumbers().slice(100));
```

And the output looks like this which I don't like the split arrays:

```
[
    2,   3,   5,   7,  11,  13,  17,  19,  23,  29,  31,  37,
   41,  43,  47,  53,  59,  61,  67,  71,  73,  79,  83,  89,
   97, 101, 103, 107, 109, 113, 127, 131, 137, 139, 149, 151,
  157, 163, 167, 173, 179, 181, 191, 193, 197, 199, 211, 223,
  227, 229, 233, 239, 241, 251, 257, 263, 269, 271, 277, 281,
  283, 293, 307, 311, 313, 317, 331, 337, 347, 349, 353, 359,
  367, 373, 379, 383, 389, 397, 401, 409, 419, 421, 431, 433,
  439, 443, 449, 457, 461, 463, 467, 479, 487, 491, 499, 503,
  509, 521, 523, 541
]
[
  547, 557, 563, 569, 571, 577, 587, 593, 599,
  601, 607, 613, 617, 619, 631, 641, 643, 647,
  653, 659, 661, 673, 677, 683, 691, 701, 709,
  719, 727, 733, 739, 743, 751, 757, 761, 769,
  773, 787, 797, 809, 811, 821, 823, 827, 829,
  839, 853, 857, 859, 863, 877, 881, 883, 887,
  907, 911, 919, 929, 937, 941, 947, 953, 967,
  971, 977, 983, 991, 997
]
```

Comment: If you attach devtools, you can expand the remaining items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To override the `maxArrayLength` directive you can use:

```js
console.dir(myArry, {'maxArrayLength': null});
```